# How to use custom html elements defined in one angular application in other application

Tags: angular

I have an application where I have some custom html elements defined. Lets says as custom-button, custom-checkbox, custom-table

Now I want to use above elements in another application. I tried including the corresponding .js files in index.html and use the custom element like any other html element but its not working

Comment: If you are talking about **Angular** you must include the `ts,html,css` files into your project and  and import the component in your main module.

Comment: Which version of Angular is it?

Comment: If custom html means components/directives in AngularJS then first of all include the appropriate .js file and put that component in html and second thing pass the appropriate binding.

Comment: Application one is developed using directives in Angular JS. I am just trying with one .js file for testing purpose so I included .js file, .css in index.html file but its not working. Any sample is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **Angular** and not **Angular JS** you must include the `ts,html,css` files into your project and and import the component in a module

Comment: I forgot to mention. Other application is using only java script and is not angular project. I tried including the css and .js files in index.html but not sure how can I include .html files. Any sample is appreciated

Comment: you can include the `.js` files and `.css` in the index file. But you wont have context  of this.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am having the same problem. Could you please let me know how can I resolve this?

Comment: Angular doesn't work on this way, if it's a third party component, try to find the angular component version in [npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/) else if the component was created by your self you must create the same component but in angular.